# php form on the fly calculated field

Tags: php, forms, calculated-field

Wondering if you can help?

I am working on a script that allows to introducing 3 fields quantity, price, discount (%), and I would like to display and store an automatic calculated field (Total) executing this operation:

quantity * price - discount(%) = Total

May you help me to code all operations in order to display (not to store) Total?

Thank you very much in advance,
Pere

This my code:

```
---dbase connect
[PHP]if($_POST["do"]=="store")
{
$prod_nombreproducto=$_POST["prod_nombreproducto"];
$prod_cantidad=$_POST["prod_cantidad"];
$prod_preciounitario=$_POST["prod_preciounitario"];
$prod_descuento=$_POST["prod_descuento"];
$prod_totalproducto=$_POST["prod_totalproducto"];[/PHP] 


[PHP]$query="insert into pm_productos value('$prod_nombreproducto','$prod_cantidad',
'$prod_preciounitario','$prod_descuento','$prod_totalproducto')";[/PHP] 


Quantity: <input type="text" name="prod_cantidad" size="20">
Price: <input type="text" name="prod_preciounitario" size="20">
Discount (%):<input type="text" name="prod_descuento" size="20">
Total:<input type="text" name="prod_totalproducto" size="20"></td>
</tr>[/PHP]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$prod_nombreproducto=$_POST["prod_nombreproducto"];
$prod_cantidad=$_POST["prod_cantidad"];
$prod_preciounitario=$_POST["prod_preciounitario"];
$prod_descuento=$_POST["prod_descuento"];
$prod_totalproducto= ($prod_preciounitario * $prod_cantidad) - $prod_descuento;
```

Like that?

When you're pulling it from the database:

```
$row = $db->fetch(); // Select/fetch data here

$total = $row['prod_preciounitario'] * $row['prod_cantidad'] - $row['prod_descuento'];

Total: <input type="text" value="<?=$total;?>">
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Curtis, but I get an error message
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /mnt/web7/...bla, bla, bla..../prod_add_probas.php on line 126

could yoy help me?
Thanks again.